# I am having" Error: Couldn't find constructor 'Builder'. ... " when trying to Run and Debug in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, debugging, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL9TE.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeqeg.png)[image: [1][Errors]]   I am having  "  Error: Couldn't find constructor 'Builder'.  ...  " when trying to Run and Debug in Visual Studio Code.

No problem with the code itself as tried to Debug few other projects and all have the same problem when debugging.

Comment: seems that you changed the actual code of those files, click on the basic.dart path and confirm that the widget names isn't changed

Comment: Is that "Builder" your custom Widget or Flutter's own widget? The "builder" widget itself takes constructor. Can you send the code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I have messed up basic.dart . After dicarding all the changes all back to normal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In main.dart file wrap your screens with builder and that screens should return something.